# Request form is empty in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have this form in a html file

```
  <form action='/data' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' id='tt' name='tt' hidden>
        <input type='text' id ='bt' name='bt'hidden>
        <input type='color' id='tc'name='tc' hidden>
        <input type='color' id = 'bc'name='bc' hidden>
        <input type='text' id = 'logo' name='logo'hidden>
        <input type='file' id='f' name='f'hidden>
      <input type='submit' id='gen' hidden>
  </form>
```

and I have confirmed that each of these have a value by doing this in the html file:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('tt').value);
// and the same for the other elements
```

However if I print the request form from my flask, it shows an empty dict. Anyone know why?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def datae():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.form
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def datae():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.form
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Try to change it

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def datae():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tt = request.form.get('tt')
        abcdxyz = request.form.get('abcdxyz')
        return what you need to return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if you want to print something from form, and return same template

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def datae():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tt = request.form.get('tt')
        abcdxyz = request.form.get('abcdxyz')
        print('this is tt',tt)
        print('this is abcdxyz',abcdxyz)
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    return render_template('/data.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: [this is what i got](https://prnt.sc/uozw4l) with [thus](https://prnt.sc/uozx0j)

Comment: wait nevermind. TT was just blank. I printed tc and it worked!

Comment: i dont understand what you need to do? to get data from form, you need use request.form.get(inputname)?

Comment: and if you want to jinja2 render same template, you can use: return redirect(request.referrer)